# how to make array of nodes?

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I have a little bit of misconception of pointers and arrays.
when I want to create an array of nodes I need a pointer right?

Is it

```
Node* array;
array = new Node[size];
```

And of course the problem is when I want to assign the node into the array

```
void Class::enqueue(int newNum)
{

    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->value = newNum;
    newNode->age = 0;

    if (isFull())
        resize();
    top++;
    array[top] = newNode; // ERROR. does this have to be a pointer?
}
```

newNode is a pointer, I understand. but if I want to dynamically allocate a Node, then I would have to use a pointer. If that is the case, then how would I assign the node into the array?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `std::vector<Node>`?? Do you really need pointers and dynamically allocated pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you want an array of nodes, but it seems that what you really want is an array of *pointers* to nodes. *newNode* in your code is a pointer, so the array should be capable of holding pointers of `Node`. Define your array as:

```
Node** array;
array = new (Node*)[size];
```

Remember to free the memory when it is no longer needed:

```
delete []array;
```

---

You can also use an array of `Node`:

```
Node* array;
array = new Node[size];

...
Node *newNode = new Node();
...
array[top] = *newNode; // dereference the pointer
```

but you should be careful because this way the contents of the node will be **copied** to the array cell. Then there will be two separate objects, holding the same data. You cannot manipulate the original node using the contents of the array.

I guess you really need an array of *pointers* to nodes :) (or as Bill said, a vector of pointers: `vector<Node*> v;`)

Comment: I actually want an array of nodes, not array of pointers to nodes. I'm having trouble if I need a dynamically allocated memory for creation of the new Node. If I need a dynamically allocated memory, I need a pointer, right? Thanks before.

Comment: If you want to be able to access the original nodes you dynamically created, you have to use an array of pointers. See my edit.

Comment: If you don't mind answering for further clarification, what does delete [] array on this point does? does it delete the dynamically allocated array and also the nodes? Thanks

Comment: @Leonard You're welcome. No, it just deletes the memory allocated for the array with `new []`, because the contents of the array are pointers. It is the reverse operation of `new []`. If you define the array as `Node *array = new Node[size];`, then the new operator allocates enough memory to hold the nodes themselves and then calls the constructors for each one. In that case, `delete []` *reverses* that operation and calls the desctructor for each node, then deletes them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* array;
```

creates an array of `Node`, it will store objects of `Node`, like

```
int* array;
```

creates an array that stores integers. However,

```
Node* newNode = new Node();
```

`new` returns a pointer to object of `Node`, i.e., `newNode`, when you try to put pointer to `Node` that expects objects of `Node`, you get that error.

Assume that your `Node` class/struct has `value` and `age` member, you can do the following:

```
Node newNode(newNum, 0); //^^call your Node's constructor that takes 2 params
array[top] = newNode;
```

to put objects of `Node` into your array of `Node`. You can also use STL containers to avoid using the dynamic array.

Comment: I understand. I'm actually trying to make an array of nodes, not array of nodes of pointers. when dynamically allocation is being used for creation of the node, then how do I assign the node into the array? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `std::vector`, you can use `std::vector<Node*> myvector;` (if you really want pointers)

Then you can do `myvector.push_back(new Node(...));` Do not forget to delete the memory, else you will have memory leaks,

If you dnt care about pointers, simply use the following (much cleaner and no need to manually free the memory)

```
std::vector<Node> myvector;
Node node;
myvector.push_back(node);
```

Comment: I think I'm allowed to use STLs but I never tried using it. I will read the documentation for using STLs

Comment: Good luck! And do read about differences between `arrays` and `vectors` -- just an example - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6321/